# How to make custom iterator interface iterable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iterator

I have an array, and i have overridden its default Iterator behavior. The problem is that, after overriding, the returned iterator becomes non iterable and for..of..loop fails on it but works on the array, but explicit call on the array's iterator next() method still works. Here is the code below:

```
let arr = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];
arr[Symbol.iterator] = function(){
  let i = 0;

  return {
    //Iterator interface
    next:function(){
      //IteratorResult Interface
      return {
        value: arr[i++]+"..",
        done: arr[i] == undefined?true:false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**And here is the iterator object**

```
let arrIterator = arr[Symbol.iterator](); //An iterator object returned but not iterable
```

**Consumption trial with for..of..loop on iterator object**

```
for (let i of arrIterator){
  console.log(i);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image: for..of..loop trial on iterator result]

**Consumption trial with for..of..loop on array**

```
for (let i of arr){
  console.log(i);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image: for..of..loop trial on array result]

**Consumption trial with explicit next() method call**

```
console.log(arrIterator.next());
console.log(arrIterator.next());
console.log(arrIterator.next());
console.log(arrIterator.next());
console.log(arrIterator.next());
console.log(arrIterator.next());
console.log(arrIterator.next());
console.log(arrIterator.next());
```

**OUTPUT**

[image: explicit next() method call on iterator result]

Please i really want to know how to make the custom iterator iterable for **for..of..loop** consumption.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement the Iterable protocol as well (*instead of just the Iterator*)

Add `[Symbol.iterator]: function() { return this; }` to your Iterator  object and it will work.

```js
let arr = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];
arr[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
  let i = 0;

  return {
    //Iterator interface
    next: function() {
      //IteratorResult Interface
      return {
        value: arr[i++] + "..",
        done: arr[i] == undefined ? true : false
      }
    },
    // Iterable interface
    [Symbol.iterator]: function() {
      return this;
    }
  }
}

let arrIterator = arr[Symbol.iterator](); //An iterator object returned but not iterable

for (let i of arrIterator) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

See [Iteration protocols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) for more info